# is there a equivalent to llvm3.6's RuntimeDyldELF::findGOTentries in llvm4.0?

Tags: c++, llvm, julia, relocation

While trying to adapt the [patch](https://github.com/JuliaLang/llvm/commit/a9e17b7f47f5afa9683fc8cfeff7020b2ff4a8b2) for LLVM 4.0 i noticed that 
`RuntimeDyldELF::findGOTentries` has been removed.

How can i implement `RuntimeDyldELF::findGOTentries` using the 4.0 api ?